# Contain a flex column of images inside a flex row

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to achieve a two-column layout with text on the left, and a column of images on the right. The column of images should be as tall as (but not taller) than the overall container for the layout. It should only take as much width as is needed to display all images in a column.

```
-------------------
| Text    | Image |
|         |-------|
|         | Image |
|         |-------|
|         | Image |
-------------------
```

However, despite multiple attempts with different markup structures, `flex` attributes, `min-height`s, `max-content`s etc, my image column always either overflows the container, or it doesn't shrink to take the least amount of width required, or the images are distorted.

A simplified example here: https://jsfiddle.net/e78hk42v

```css
/* Decoration */

html {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
}

aside {
  background: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

article {
  border: 10px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  /* Define the size of the overall panel */
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 90vh;
}


/* Column of images */

aside>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}


/* Each image container */


/* More reliable to have containers with half-padding, than apply a margin to bare images */

figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <main>
    <p>Hello hello hello hello</p>
  </main>

  <aside>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </aside>
</article>
```

How can I style this layout, so that the column of images is contained within the layout, and takes the least amount of horizontal space possible, while maintaining the aspect ratio of the images?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Do the images potentially have different aspect ratios? And please put the code into your question as it is already being marked for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Set to `aside > div { height: 100%; display: grid; grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr); }`.
And for `img { width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover; }`.
Here is an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

article {
  --gap: 10px;
  border: var(--gap) solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 90vh;
}


main {
  padding: 20px;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: var(--gap);
  background: black;
}

aside > div {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  gap: var(--gap);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

figure {
  min-height:0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <main>
    <p>Hello hello hello hello</p>
  </main>
  
  <aside>
    <div>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </aside>
</article>
```